# How to add shaders to a video and play in mediaPlayerelement without getting error?

Tags: c#, windows, shader, winui-3

I am trying to add gray shaders to a video file here is my code.
GrayscaleVideoEffect.cs

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.Graphics.DirectX.Direct3D11;
    using Windows.Media.Effects;
    using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
   using Windows.Storage.Streams;
    using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;

    namespace App1
    { 
    ///


    /// Applies custom video effect to a media clip, transforming RGB colours to grayscale.
    /// Please note that video effects must be implemented in Windows Runtime Components.
    ///

    public sealed class GrayscaleVideoEffect : IBasicVideoEffect
    {
    ///

    /// This means that the video effect won't modify the source frame.
    ///

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
     get { return true; } 
     }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returning an empty list will provide frames in ARGB32 format.
    /// Strangely, the frame bitmaps will be provided in BRGA32 instead.
    /// See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.effects.ibasicvideoeffect.supportedencodingproperties
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyList<VideoEncodingProperties> SupportedEncodingProperties
    {
        get { return new List<VideoEncodingProperties>(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Our video effect will do all processing in the CPU.
    /// </summary>
    public MediaMemoryTypes SupportedMemoryTypes
    {
        get { return MediaMemoryTypes.Cpu; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The video effect is time independent - any frame of the video will be able to be processed.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TimeIndependent
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the video effect is unloaded, and used for freeing any used resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reason"></param>
    public void Close(MediaEffectClosedReason reason)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the decoding process needs to skip frames.
    /// </summary>
    public void DiscardQueuedFrames()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for applying our video effect to a single frame. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
    {
        var inputFrameBitmap = context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

        // Create intermediate buffer for holding the frame pixel data.
        var frameSize = inputFrameBitmap.PixelWidth * inputFrameBitmap.PixelHeight * 4;
        var frameBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer((uint)frameSize);

        // Copy bitmap data from the input frame.
        inputFrameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(frameBuffer);

        // Iterate through all pixels in the frame.
        var framePixels = frameBuffer.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i += 4)
        {
            // Calculate the luminance based on the RGB values - this way we can convert it to grayscale.
            var bValue = framePixels[i];
            var gValue = framePixels[i + 1];
            var rValue = framePixels[i + 2];

            var luminance = ((rValue / 255.0f) * 0.2126f) +
                            ((gValue / 255.0f) * 0.7152f) +
                            ((bValue / 255.0f) * 0.0722f);

            // Set the pixel data to the calculated grayscale values.
            framePixels[i] = framePixels[i + 1] = framePixels[i + 2] = (byte)(luminance * 255.0f);
        }

        // Copy the modified frame data to the output frame.
        context.OutputFrame.SoftwareBitmap.CopyFromBuffer(framePixels.AsBuffer());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the encoding properties change.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encodingProperties"></param>
    /// <param name="device"></param>
    public void SetEncodingProperties(VideoEncodingProperties encodingProperties, IDirect3DDevice device)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called for passing any custom parameters to the video effect.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    public void SetProperties(IPropertySet configuration)
    {
    }
    }
    }
```

here is my MainWindow.Xaml.cs

```
     using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
     using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
     using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
     using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
     using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections; 
    using Windows.Media.Core;
     using Windows.Media.Editing;
     using Windows.Media.Effects;
     using WinRT.Interop;
     // To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
     // and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

     namespace App1
     {
    ///


    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame. 
    ///

    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
     this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void VideoPlayer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Load video file
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        var windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(picker, windowHandle);
        var videoFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        // Create a MediaClip from the video file and apply our video effect

        MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);

        // Create an instance of your custom video effect
        var effect = new GrayscaleVideoEffect();

        // Create a VideoEffectDefinition with your custom effect
        var videoEffectDefinition = new VideoEffectDefinition(effect.GetType().FullName);

        // Add the VideoEffectDefinition to the MediaClip's VideoEffectDefinitions collection
                 clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(videoEffectDefinition);

        // Create a MediaComposition object that will allow us to generate a stream source
        MediaComposition compositor = new MediaComposition();
        compositor.Clips.Add(clip);

        // Set the stream source to the MediaElement control
        var mediaStreamSource = compositor.GenerateMediaStreamSource();

        // Create a MediaSource object from the media stream source
        var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);

        // Set the media source of the MediaPlayerElement
        VideoPlayer.Source = mediaSource;
    }

    }
    }
```

```
      here is my Xaml Code
```

This is code for UI which has a mediaplayerelement player

```
 
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">     <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="VideoPlayer" Loaded="VideoPlayer_Loaded" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />       </StackPanel>
```

```
 i keep getting class not registered error for this code
    var videoEffectDefinition = new VideoEffectDefinition(effect.GetType().FullName);
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered (0x80040154             (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Any idea how to fix it?
```

I have a WinUI3 app this code works perfectly fine on UWP but on WinUI3 i get a run time error for class not registered. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible code with files including project file instead of raw copy / paste https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://github.com/r2d2rigo/UWP-Samples/tree/master/CustomVideoEffect - this is for UWP i want to run the same code in winui3 how how to do that?

Comment: Ok I thought you had a WinUI3 project already. You'll have to work a bit more before someone can help I guess. There's an example of combining the two here https://github.com/kaesardev/CustomEffectsWinRT you can look for inspiration before coming back here with reproducible problem.

Comment: Could you please tell us what version of the Windows App SDK are you using? I suggest you should try to use windows app sdk 1.2 and the later. Refer to the thread: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5172

Comment: i just copy pasted it to a blank winui3 app and tried to run it with no changes. I get a class not registered error. my windows app sdk is 1.2.221109.1. i have tried to change it to x64 any cpu x86 all that but doesnt seem to make a difference